# how to install specific package and version for centos

Tags: php, centos, rpm, yum

ill try to install specific version of php in centos
https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-php-7-centos-7-rhel-7-server/

```
yum install epel-release yum-utils -y
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
yum install php php-common php-opcache php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql -y
```

now when i try to install different package for eg. `yum install svn`, got this error

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from remi-release: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

is their a much convenient way on installing specific package and version for centos **Thank you**

Comment: Looks like you have a corrupted repo configuration file (bad baseurl). For proper installation see the Wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 0):

looks like remi-release repo's baseurl is not available or has been deleted, you should remove it from your yum repo's and clean local yum cache

```
rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php70.repo.rpmsave
yum clean all
```